# How to find definition for $a^r$ when r is any real number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I was foraying into an advanced high school maths textbook and found this question -- For exponent $a^r$,

If $r = 0$ then $$a^r = 1$$
If $r$ is a natural number, then $$a^r=a^{r-1}.r$$
If $r$ is a negative integer, then $$a^r={\frac1{a^{-r}}}$$
If $r$ is a rational number, so that $r = p/g$ in lowest form, then $$a^r = a^{p/g}$$

The question asks to give a definition for all $a^r$ when $r$ is any real number. My problem with this one is that it's the first time I've encountered a question such as this and I'm not sure where to start.

Please point me in the right direction. I know some properties of real numbers (commutative, distributive etc.) but how do I use them here to make a definition of $a^r$ for all real $r$?

Comment: You (or your reference) meant to write $a^r=a^{r-1}\times a$.

Comment: To your main question, it's hard to answer without knowing what sort of answer is expected.  A quick answer would be $a^r=e^{r\ln a}$.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Thank you! That part makes so much more sense now.

Comment: This question is before the introduction to complex numbers chapter so I'm supposing that I can't use complex numbers. But I'm interested in how you made a definition like that so quickly! Can you explain the thought process behind how you got $a^r=e^{rlna}$, I'll try to follow?

Comment: One possible definition is $a^r = \sup \{ a^q \mid q \in \mathbb Q, q \leq r \}$.

Comment: This is the usual definition, and it has nothing to do with complex numbers (I'm assuming you forget to specify $a>0$).  The usual approach is to define $e^x$ and $\ln x$ as inverse functions  (either by power series or by some definite integral) and then to define $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$.  But again, you appear to be jumping into the middle of a longish  story.

Comment: As to how someone thinks of such definitions, one answer is that if you read real analysis textbooks they define $a^r$ precisely, so you see various possible definitions in various books.

Comment: @lulu I think it is somewhat cycle definition as we define $\ln{x}$ by the number $y$ such that $e^{y} = x$. So you cannot define $a^r$ by logarithm. Also you cannot define $e^r$.

Comment: @Ziec  That's simply not how it works.  In the standard approaches, either one defines $\ln x$ via an integral, or one defines $e^x$ via a power series, and then defines the other as the inverse of the defined function.  the usual properties of exponents and logs are then deduced.  But this is my point:  background is needed.  This is not a one or two paragraph business.

Comment: @Zieac We can do it but we must do it carefully. One approach (see Spivak’s Calculus) is to define $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, dt$. Then we define the exponential function to be the inverse function of the natural log function. Then we are free to define $a^r = e^{r \ln a}$. Other ways of defining these various functions are also possible. Different real analysis books take different approaches.

Comment: @lulu Yes I do think I'm doing some jumping above my level. I'll do some brushing up on $e^x$ and natural logarithm before tackling this question again. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu Ok thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @lulu mentioned, it is difficult to answer, for example, I do not know what theory you are assuming true to ask your question. You can see it in three quite natural ways:

1. If you assume that the exponentials and logarithms are well defined with the properties that are already known, then it would be easy to see this:

> Let $r\in \mathbb R$, then we define $a^r:=e^{r\ln a}$, then for example $$a^ra^s=e^{r\ln a}e^{s\ln a}=e^{(r+s)\ln a}=a^{r+s},\; etc.$$

2. If we assume that you have already carried out sequences, we can rely on the density of rational numbers:

> Let $r\in \mathbb R$, then exists a sequence $(r_n)\subset\mathbb Q$ such that $r_n\to r$. SO we can define $a^r=a^{\lim_{n\to \infty}r_n}$, for example in this case let $r,s\in \mathbb R$, then exists $(r_n), (s_n)\subset\mathbb Q$ s.t. $r_n\to r$ and $s_n\to s$. Hence $$a^ra^s=a^{\lim r_n}a^{\lim s_n}=\lim a^{r_n}\lim a^{s_n}=\lim a^{r_n}a^{s_n}=\lim a^{r_n+s_n}=a^{\lim(r_n+s_n)}=a^{r+s},\;etc...$$

3. Assuming that you have done the definition of the real numbers in an axiomatic way and not completely from the rationals, that is, you already have the axiom of the supreme:

> Let $r\in\mathbb R$, then we can define $a^r:=\sup\{a^q:q\in\mathbb Q\wedge q\leq r\}$ or $a^r:=\inf\{a^q:q\in\mathbb Q\wedge q\geq r\}$.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I wouldn’t say it’s difficult, I’d just say various definitions are possible. Definitions 2 and 3 are very intuitive and are I’d guess what the question is looking for.

Comment: @littleO I think it was misunderstood, the question is not difficult to answer in itself. What is really difficult is knowing what approach the MO is looking for. And this is given by the great variety of options as seen in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The book book is using a bootstrapping method of defining the $a^x$ which parallels the hierarchy the book used to define the systems of numbers.

I imagine the book started by doing something like, starting with the numbers $0$ and $1$, and then defined the natural numbers by saying something like, start with $0$ and then successively add $1$ to get the next number, all the numbers achieved are the *natural numbers*.

This parallels the definition of $a^n$ for $n$ being a natural number.  Start with $a^0 = 1$ and then successively multiply by $a$ to get $a^{\text{the next number}}$ and all the values of $a^n; n\in \mathbb N$ will be acheived.

Then I imagine the book did something like saying:  we define negative integers as defining for any natural number $n$, we define $-n$ as the number which solves $x + n = 0$.

In parallel, if $-n$ is the number so that $(-n) + n = 0$ then $a^{-1}$ is the number so that $a^{-n}\cdot a^n = 1$.   In other words, $a^{-n} = \frac 1{a^n}$.

And then I imagine that the booked defined $\frac 1n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ as the number so that $(\frac 1n) \times n = 1$.

In parallel, then $a^{\frac 1n}$ is the number $w$ so that $w^n = a$.  That is $a^{\frac 1n}$ is the positive $n$th root of $a$. (Note: we are assuming $a > 0$).

And we define the rational numbers by saying that a rational number is ratio between an integer and a natural number.  That is $r\in \mathbb Q$ then there is an integer $m$ and an natural number $n$ so that $r = \frac mn = a\times \frac 1n$.

And we define $a^r = a^{\frac mn}$ as $(a^\frac 1n)^m$.  Remember that $a^{\frac 1n}$ is the positive $n$th root of $a$ so $a^{\frac mn}$ will be the positive $n$th root of $a$ to the $m$th (integer) power.

Or you seeing how every step of identifying the hierarchy of number systems is reflected in how the book defines $a^x$ for those number systems.

So now we get to how did the book define the real numbers.  I do not know as I have not read the book.  Your job is to go through the book as see precisely how it did it.

But I imagine one way or another it said something about how every real number $x$ will have a series of rational numbers $q_1, q_2, q_3, etc$ that get closer and closer but "never reach" $x$.  How precise and technical the text gets in defining the reals will vary from class to class and book to book.

Now I imagine your book wants to define $a^x$ in a parallel way.  If $q_1, q_2, q_3, etc$ are a series of rational number that get closer and closer but "never reach" $x$.  Then $a^{q_1}, a^{q_2}, a^{q_3}, etc.$ will be a series of real numbers that get close to some real number value.  That real number value will be what we define as $a^x$.

Now that's a pretty handwavy and flaky definition.  But it can be made more precise by noting how this particular text defined the real numbers.

======

That is what I think the book wants you to do it.

But I'd be remiss if I didn't mention many if not most books take a calculus type approach where they completely forget about the definitions of $a^r$ where $r$ is a natural number, or an integer, or a rational number.  Instead they reinvent to wheel.

The note that $\int_1^a \frac 1t dt$ is one to one and onto function from any real number $a$ to the positive real numbers.

So they define $Ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1t dt$.

Then they take the inverse of that function and define $Exp(x)=w$ where $w$ is the value where $Ln(w) = x$.

Then they define $a^x = Exp(Ln(a))$.  And then it will turn out that that definition will be equal to the definition we always knew before.

But I don't think you book is taking that approach.